# PHP Ajax showhints as user starts typing

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to understand and apply Ajax functionality to my site. But i faced with some questions and I need some explanation . Here is a code that I get from w3school.com:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0)
    { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
             document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
<form action=""> 
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 

</body>
</html>

// and here is gethint.php code

<?php
// Fill up array with names
$a[]="Anna";
$a[]="Brittany";
$a[]="Cinderella";
$a[]="Diana";
$a[]="Eva";
$a[]="Fiona";
$a[]="Gunda";
$a[]="Hege";
$a[]="Inga";
$a[]="Johanna";
$a[]="Kitty";
$a[]="Linda";
$a[]="Nina";
$a[]="Ophelia";
$a[]="Petunia";
$a[]="Amanda";
$a[]="Raquel";
$a[]="Cindy";
$a[]="Doris";
$a[]="Eve";
$a[]="Evita";
$a[]="Sunniva";
$a[]="Tove";
$a[]="Unni";
$a[]="Violet";
$a[]="Liza";
$a[]="Elizabeth";
$a[]="Ellen";
$a[]="Wenche";
$a[]="Vicky";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_REQUEST["q"]; $hint="";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len = strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name,0,$len))) {
            if ($hint==="") { $hint=$name; }
            else { $hint .= ", $name"; }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or output the correct values
echo $hint==="" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

But I have the following questions:

1. why we use `str.length==0`? because I thought it should be
   `fname.length==0`
2. what is  the use of `q="+str in "gethint.php?q="+str` part?
3. why we use `$q=$_REQUEST["q"]`? because I thought it should be
   `$q=$_REQUEST["fname"]`

Answer (score 1):

1:  str.length==0 will check if entered string should  at least 1 character long or not null.
2:  q="+str" in gething.php?q="+str" --- it means once you enter any character from this url it will start looking entered character in database by passing(appending) str as parameters in the **url**.
3:  $q=$_REQUEST["q"] .. would get the value passed in **url** as parameters.

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

str.length==0? its optional. if you feel its needy then use it else abort .actually this is for showing the result to the innerHTML

q="+str in "gethint.php?q="+str part?   bcz xmlhttp.open("GET","gethint.php?q="+str,true); in this xmlhttp.open pass varible in two methods like GET or POST
SO it need to pass the variable where your full data is stored like q from here it pass the value and showing results by use of xmlhttp.send();